# Conditional Not Null Constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table, check-constraints

Is there a way to model the following behaviour with constraint checks (or other functions) in postgres SQL:

I have two columns:

- `oncost (boolean)`
- `oncostdescription (varchar)`

If oncost is `true`, i want `oncostdescription` to be mandatory (`NOT NULL`, `NOT EMPTY`)

If concost is `false`, i want `oncostdescription` not to be mandatory (`NULL`, `EMPTY`)

**EDIT:**
I forgot to state my postgres version being lower than 12.
Some folks here came up with a cool feature called `generated columns`.
Seems pretty cool. But only if you have 12+

Comment: Maybe remove `oncost`, because it is redundant?

Comment: I'd consider a check constraint that rejects "empty" values.

Comment: Please don't add *the solution* to your question. It is already in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `check` constraint:

```
create table mytable (
    oncost boolean
    oncostdescription varchar(50),
    constraint ck_mytable check(
        not oncost 
        or not (oncostdescription is null or oncostdescription = '')
    )
)
```

This phrases as: either the boolean flag is false, or the description is neither null nor empty.

You could also express this as:

```
create table mytable (
    oncost boolean
    oncostdescription varchar(50),
    constraint ck_mytable check(
        not (
            oncost 
            and (oncostdescription is null or oncostdescription = '')
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Your first suggestion did the job! Nice!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, a generated column may do what you want:

```
create table t (
     . . . 
     oncostdescription varchar,
     oncost boolean generated always as (oncostdescription is not null)
);
```

This assumes that you want `oncost` as a boolean flag indicating whether or not `oncostdescription` has a value -- which is consistent with how the question is phrased.

Comment: Thank you, but i forgot to state my postgres version being lower than 12. This feature `generated` is apparently only for version +12 - see here https://pgdash.io/blog/postgres-12-generated-columns.html

Comment: @ThomasLang . . . Perhaps a view is sufficient, then.  I wouldn't recommend actually storing the value, if you just want a flag.

Answer (score 1):

The `oncost` column is redundant (fully dependant on `oncostdescription`), so it can be computed when desired. Postgres-12 supports `generated always as ...` columns:

---

```
CREATE TABLE omg
        ( seq integer not null generated always as identity
        , oncostdescription varchar
        , oncost boolean NOT NULL generated always as ( oncostdescription IS NOT NULL AND oncostdescription > '') STORED
        );

insert into omg(oncostdescription) VALUES ( NULL), (''), ('a'), (' ');

select * from omg;
```

---

Result:

---

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 4
 seq | oncostdescription | oncost 
-----+-------------------+--------
   1 |                   | f
   2 |                   | f
   3 | a                 | t
   4 |                   | t
(4 rows)
```

---

And sice the `oncost` field is computable, it could also be packed in a view:
(with exactly the same result)

---

```
CREATE VIEW vomg AS
SELECT seq, oncostdescription
        , ( oncostdescription IS NOT NULL AND oncostdescription > '')::boolean AS oncost
FROM omg
        ;

SELECT * FROM vomg;
```